# Calling servlet from tomcat throws HTTP Status 500 java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat7

I am new to J2EE and build a sample project using tomcat and eclipse. While the index.html load properly but when i submit the page (or make call to servlet), i received below exception

```
HTTP Status 500 - 
type Exception report
message 
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1641)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Following are the files i have created

1) index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="SelectCoffee.do">
select coffee
<select name="taste" size="1">
<option value="dark">dark</option>
<option value="latte">latte</option>
<option value="cold">cold</option>
<option value="chocolate">chocolate</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

2)web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"  version="2.4">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>For Coffee</servlet-name>
<sevlet-class>com.example.web.CoffeeSelect</sevlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>For Coffee</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/SelectCoffee.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

3) CoffeeSelect.java

```
package com.example.web;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CoffeeSelect extends HttpServlet{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException,ServletException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Cofee Advice");
    String c= "mine : " + request.getParameter("taste");
    out.println("<br>Got taste = "+c);
}}
```

Also let me know if anything else is required. Please help as this may get me a job :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your webb.xml there is a typo in servlet class definition it should be `<servlet-class> </servlet-class>` not `<servet-class> </servet-class>` probably the servlet is never registered, that is why you are getting a **NullpointerExcepion**

Answer (score 1):

This would perfectly work. Don't write the logic in doPost() do it in processRequest()

> index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/SelectCoffee">
select coffee
<select name="taste" size="1">
<option value="dark">dark</option>
<option value="latte">latte</option>
<option value="cold">cold</option>
<option value="chocolate">chocolate</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>CoffeeSelect</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>CoffeeSelect</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CoffeeSelect</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SelectCoffee</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

> CoffeeSelect.java

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {


out.println("Cofee Advice");
String c= "mine : " + request.getParameter("taste");
out.println("<br>Got taste = "+c);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not make difference you can use your custom name in url-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Does the `class CoffeeSelect` built into the class folder? In the wrong hint, it may be the class is not found.

Answer (score 0):

check with `request.getParameterValues("taste");`
and If possible remove the space from the `servlet-name`

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status 500 tells there is an error in server side software that stops fulfilling a request.
Learn more about [HTTP  Status codes  here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) those will make your job easy while debugging your webapplication.

Check your Deployment descriptor (**web.xml**) there is an error while registering servlet class
so you are getting null pointer exception.
Replace your web.xml with this now it will definetly works

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"  version="2.4">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>For Coffee</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.example.web.CoffeeSelect</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>For Coffee</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/SelectCoffee.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```